# Grouping the nodes by matching attribute

Tags: xslt

My input xml looks as shown below,
I need to group the  tag based on the  id attribute. 
Even if the id attribute of  tag is same in the next row, then it should be grouped under the previous  tag.

```
<Layouts>
<Layout id="1">
<Structure id="2000">
<Row id="1">
<Col id="125"/>
</Row>
<Row id="2">
<Col id="126"/>
</Row>
<Row id="3">
<Col id="125"/>
</Row>
</Structure>
</Layout>

<Layout id="2">
<Structure id="3000">
<Row id="1">
<Col id="125"/>
</Row>
<Row id="2">
<Col id="226"/>
</Row>
<Row id="3">
<Col id="226"/>
</Row>
<Row id="4">
<Col id="125"/>
</Row>
</Structure>
</Layout>
</Layouts>
```

My output xml should look like this,

```
<Layouts>
<Layout id="1">
<Structure id="2000">
<Row id="1">
<Col id="125"/>
<Col id="125"/>
</Row>
<Row id="2">
<Col id="126"/>
</Row>          
</Structure>
</Layout>

<Layout id="2">
<Structure id="3000">
<Row id="1">
<Col id="125"/>
<Col id="125"/>
</Row>
<Row id="2">
<Col id="226"/>
<Col id="226"/>
</Row>          
</Structure>
</Layout>
</Layouts>
```

As we can see, each row should be grouped with similar  id attribute values and finally it should be displayed in a single . 
This grouping should only happen for each  section.
For each  node, the similar  id's should be grouped inside  node.
I tried the xsl:for-each-group, but the  id's are not getting grouped exactly inside . Can anyone pls help..

Comment: Please do a search for XSLT grouping - it's probably the most often asked question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: You say you have tried xsl:for-each group, so can you show the XSLT you have tried so far, please? It doesn't matter that it may not work. You might not be that far off a solution! Thanks!

Comment: Can you have mode than one "Col" element per "Row" in your input XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all you need to group is the `Col` elements and you can use XSLT 2.0 here is a stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Structure">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="Col/@id">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , current-group()/node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```